# Two tables join data passing to view in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, join

need to get data from status table in view. Tried to put alias, googled over 3 hours, I'm lost. Any ideas how?

Controler code:

```
 $action= DB::table('actionplan')
    ->join('status','actionplan.status','=','status.id')
    ->select('status.name as testas','actionplan.*')
    ->where([['user_id','=',$name],['done','<>',1]])->get();
```

View code:

```
@foreach($teams as $item)
<th scope="row">1</th>
<td>{{$item->name}}</td>
<td>{{$item->start_date}}</td>
<td>{{$item->end_date}}</td>
<td>{{$item->comment}}</td>
<td>{{$item->status()->name}}</td>
```

Comment: Create relations among models, and it will be more simpler hasMany,hasOne, belongsTo etc

Comment: @Poria I don't see any models here.

Comment: Your code shows you defining an alias, however you don't seem to be using it. It should be `{{$item->testas}}`

Comment: @apokryfos well thats a comment only !

Comment: @Poria I mean I don't think the OP has defined models for the specific tables (or possibly not for all of them).

Answer (score 0):

You should really implement models for your database tables. While this isn't the advice you're asking for, it will greatly simplify your queries in this regard.

Your **ActionPlan.php** model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

class ActionPlan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'actionplan';

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(App\Status::class, 'id', 'status');
    }
}
```

Your **Status.php** model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

class Status extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'status';
}
```

Your query:

```
$actions = Action::whereHas('status')
    ->where('user_id', '=', $name)
    ->where('done', '<>', 1)
    ->get();
```

Or:

```
$actions = Action::whereHas('status')
    ->whereUserId($name)
    ->having('done', '<>', 1)
    ->get();
```